# Reorganizer Project in django-CMS

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone I have a project works with this characteristic!

```
Django==1.8.14
django-cms==3.2.5
Python 2.7.12
```

my project work fine, but now I am trying to reorganizer my apps

Right now I have something like this

[image]

in my case `api_cpujobs, APIchart, drawChart, cms_extensions and readRSS` are apps, so to reorganizer I create a folder inside portal calls `apps` and move there my apps.

I modified my `setting.py`

so now I have this

```
'portal',
'portal.apps.APIchart',
'portal.apps.drawChart',
'portal.apps.readRSS',
'portal.apps.cms_extensions',
```

But when I start the server  I obtain this error

```
ImportError: No module named apps
```

I look for in internet and even other tutorial have the same organization, but I don't find  what am I missing?

Thank in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but try it that way:

```
'portal',`
'APIchart',
'drawChart',
...
```

That should work, if it doesn't fix the issue, let me know :)

Comment: thanks @Philipp Zettl  I try to and the error that say is `No module named readRSS` even I create a new django cms  project  (empty) create the folder apps and add only one plugin, in this case `readRSS` inside the folder `apps` give me the same error, but more weird is that I put outside the folder `apps` in the new project has the same error

Comment: Okay, @stone so it worked for you, when you've created all apps and now you're on your way to reorganize the whole project. Did i get that right?

Comment: I've just found a - for me - perfect way to create django webapps using that ["Tutorial"](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/)

Comment: [Here's](http://web.archive.org/web/20170610031157/https://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/) a archived link for the website in my last comment.